# Conversion failed when converting the varchar. Working with cursors from t-sql

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, windows-server-2012

I am using T-SQL and cursors to list the `emp` database.

Here's my code:

```
DECLARE cursors CURSOR FOR 
   SELECT 
       emp.Ename, emp.Sal 
   FROM Emp 
   WHERE Sal > 200

DECLARE @surname VARCHAR(50), @salary INT

PRINT 'Employees earning more than 200:'

OPEN cursors
FETCH NEXT FROM cursors INTO @surname, @salary

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
        PRINT @surname + ' ' + @salary
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursors INTO @surname, @salary
END

CLOSE cursors
DEALLOCATE cursors
```

The problem is that when I try to execute the code I am getting this message:

> Employees earning more than 200: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SMITH ' to data
>   type int.

Did I do something wrong? How to solve it?

Comment: I have similar error, but my loop falls after it looped through whole scope :-( Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to add an integer to a string in this line: `PRINT @surname + ' ' + @salary`

The way to fix this is to convert the `@salary` on that line to varchar with `CONVERT` or `CAST` Here is a way to do it with `CONVERT`:

```
PRINT @surname + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(100), @salary)
```

Here is a way to convert the int to varchar with `CAST`:

```
PRINT @surname + ' ' + CAST(@salary AS varchar(100))
```

Be sure to set the number in `varchar` to accommodate for the maximum number of digits that `@salary` will have, or else you will get this error:

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type varchar.
```

As to why it is complaining about `SMITH` being converted to int it is because of [Data Type Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx). Data types with lower precedence tries to get converted to data types of higher precedence. `varchar` has a lower precedence than `int`, hence `SMITH` trying to be converted to an int.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may need to convert/cast @salary to a varchar to print it:

```
 PRINT @surname + ' ' + convert(varchar(10),@salary)
```